# R - How to generate a list of data frames and write them into excel with lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply, xlsx

So this might be pretty nuanced, but the fundamentals I'm struggling with is: using lapply to filter a few main data frame to create a number of small data frames. Combining those small data frames (which are related because they share a filter) into a multi-sheet excel document.

I have these packages enabled:

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr); library(XLConnect); 
library(rJava); library(xlsxjars); library(xlsx); 
library(tidyr)
```

I'm able to get the desired output very manually, but I'm sure there is a way to leverage functions like lapply (or maybe another one of the apply functions) in order to run this a little quicker.

My original data is much larger, so I'll use the following example:

```
df1
   Code   Color   Value
[1] A      Red     10
[2] A      Blue    15
[3] A      Red     5
[4] B      Green   20
[5] B      Red     15 
[6] C      Green   10


df2
   Code   Level   Value
[1] A      All     150
[5] B      All     200
[6] C      All     500
```

For the sake of this example, let's assume that df1 and df2 are unrelated except for the fact that they share "Code".

I start out with two lists that specify which codes belong to each "Person" (where each person has a unique list of "Codes" but these "Codes" can belong to more than one person).

```
JoeCodes <- c("A","B","C")
JohnCodes <- c("A","B")
MaryCodes <- c("C")
```

This is where things get difficult for me. I know I can do:

```
Joedf1 <- df1 %>% filter(Code %in% JoeCodes)
Joedf2 <- df2 %>% filter(Code %in% JoeCodes)
```

Then if I want to write this into Excel I use

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Joedf1), file="Joe.xlsx", sheetName="Joedf1", row.names=FALSE, showNA=FALSE)
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Joedf2), file="Joe.xlsx", sheetName="Joedf2", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, showNA=FALSE)
```

I repeat the process for John and Mary. Now, the reality is that I have a 13 peoples to filter for on 6 different data frames. This get's cumbersome as the list can change and only grows by the month.

My thinking is that I should be able to accomplish something like this:

```
AllPersons <- c("JoeCodes","JohnCodes","MaryCodes")
```

and then use something like lapply to filter df1 for all lists in "AllPersons" and generate the following data frames in "Joedf1", "Johndf1", "Marydf1".

Then repeat the process to filter df2 to generate data frames "Joedf2","Johndf2", "Marydf2"

Then create new lists (I could see how this step might be able to be simplified since each data frame has the name in it, but I have no idea how I would accomplish that):

```
JoeAll <- c("Joedf1","Joedf2")
JohnAll <- c("Johndf1","Johndf2")
MaryAll <- c("Marydf1","Marydf2")

AllFrames <- c("JoeAll", "JohnAll", "MaryAll")
```

From there I would want to use write.xlsx to create spreadsheet for each list in AllFrames and a sheet for each underlying data frame.

Does what I want to do make sense? I feel really stuck on a conceptual level.

Any help/guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work for you, I included some sample data. There is no need for `lapply`, a simple for loop also works fine. You could also wrap the body of the for loop in a function and call that from `lapply`, but it does not add value here.

```
df1=data.frame(Code=c('A','A','B','B'),test=c(1,1,1,1))
df2=df1

library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

JoeCodes <- c("A","B","C")
JohnCodes <- c("A","B")
MaryCodes <- c("C")

allCodes = list(Joe = JoeCodes, John = JohnCodes,Mary = MaryCodes)

for(i in 1:length(allCodes))
{
  df1_subset <- df1 %>% filter(Code %in% allCodes[[i]])
  df2_subset <- df2 %>% filter(Code %in% allCodes[[i]])
  name = names(allCodes)[i]
  if(nrow(df1_subset)>0)
  write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df1_subset), file=paste0(name,".xlsx"), sheetName=paste0(name,"df1"), row.names=FALSE, showNA=FALSE)
  if(nrow(df2_subset)>0)
  write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df2_subset), file=paste0(name,".xlsx"), sheetName=paste0(name,"df2"), append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, showNA=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this did exactly what I wanted! I think sometimes my mind jumps to lapply because I'm not yet proficient in the art of looping. I'm able to do most things the long way, as a novice, so now I'm always looking for ways to simplify the code and make it more manageable.